# Framework7, Cordova and Angular2

Tags: cordova, angular, html-framework-7

I want to use `Framework7` for UI,`Angular2` for data binding, `Cordova` to compile into mobile app.

I know for `Framework7` and `Cordova` is straight forward. I just replace the `index.html` in `Cordova` with all the `Framework7 index.html` then copy in files and folders. And it works.

But it seems like `Angular2` is more complex. I know there are tutorial for integration of `Angularjs` and `Framework7`.

What is the proper way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

[This post](https://www.timo-ernst.net/blog/2017/02/08/using-angular-with-framework7-in-2017/) might give you some directions how feasible `Framework7` and `Angular` integration is.